# Width of element in percents of height. HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set `width` in CSS in percents of `height`? Like on picture:

[image]

Comment: I think you will have to do this via js !

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set height like that in css.

There is little use even if You can,  because different users have different preferences about using toolbar which occupy height on monitor, some even have multiple lines of bookmarks, some view Web in full screen - therefore there is no point of setting page layout according to browser height.

Only good recommendation is setting width to 1000px because most current day monitor resolutions can display that without horizontal scroll.